# Scroll bar inside a sortable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jQuery sortable.  Inside the sortable div is div that has a vertical scrollbar.  If  I click the vertical scroll bar, the sortable is triggered but doesn't see the unclick event.  I then need to right click in order to drop the sortable div.  How can i propagate the unclick or even make it so the scrollbar does not trigger the sortable drag?

```
$('#sortHolder').sortable();
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/L2hWv/

There is this similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460086/jqueryui-sortable-failed-with-scrolling), but I have a scrolling div inside my sortable.

Comment: I have faced your issue with a flash object inside the div. You could try using a drag handle. Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle

Comment: Perfect, add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced your issue with a flash object inside the div. You could try using a drag handle. Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-handle